# GPS application not working fine on device

Tags: android, android-studio, gps

I have developed a small android app in android studio. I placed a button and on button click it should show me the current `gps` location of me. I followed a tutorial and test the app on my device which has `marshmallow 6.0.1`. But when i tried to test it on lower `OS` it shows me `0,0` coordinates. I don't know why it's happening.

Bellow is my code for `GPS`

**GPSTracker**

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 5; // 5 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 10000; // 10 seconds

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            Log.i("", "Network Value: " + isNetworkEnabled);
            Log.i("", "GPS Value: " + isGPSEnabled);
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                        this
                );
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {

                    location = locationManager

                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();

                        longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    }

                }

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {



                 return location;

              }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    }
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("", "Exception " + e);

    }
    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {

   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
  }

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
    getLatitude();
    getLongitude();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}}
```

Bellow is my main activity code

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnShowLocation;
TextView textShowLocation;
// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    btnShowLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    textShowLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textShowLocation);
    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    finish();
                }
                return;
            }
                     // other 'case' lines to check for other
                        // permissions this app might request
        }
    }




        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //textShowLocation.setText("");
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                textShowLocation.append("Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude+ "\nLong: " + longitude);
            }
            else
            {
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }
    });



}}
```

**Update 1**

Bellow is my manifest file

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.accurat.tracker">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>



<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

It's working perfect on latest android `OS` but as already told it's not working good for lower than `marshmallow`

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: post your manifest file too.

Comment: @ChintanBawa kindly see the updated code